# Searching for palindromes with for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Simple code looking for palindromes. Wanted to do this without sequence (split -> reverse -> join -> compare). So i'm iterating. And i'm doing it wrong. Why?

```
function palindrome(str) {
str.toLowerCase().replace(/\[W_]/g, "").split('');
 var j=str.length-1;
  for (var i=0; i<str.length/2; i++)
{ 
if (str[i]!=str[j])
     return false;
  j--;

}
return true;
}


palindrome("race car");
```

Comment: `Wanted to do this without sequence (split -> reverse -> join -> compare).` Why?

Comment: Note you don't actually need `.split('')` because strings accept array lookup notation: `"racecar"[0] == 'r'` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your regex. It should be `/[\W_]/g`. Also, you forgot to assign the result to `str`. `.replace()` doesn't modify the original string, because strings in JavaScript are immutable.

Fixed code:

```
function palindrome(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]/g, "").split('');
  var j=str.length-1;
  for (var i=0; i<str.length/2; i++) { 
    if (str[i]!=str[j])
      return false;
    j--;
  }
  return true;
}


palindrome("race car");
```

Comment: what's the difference between /\W/g and /\W_/g?

Comment: @Sebastian `/\W_/g` matches any non-word character and `_` character after it.

Comment: @Sebastian If you want to match any non-word characters or the underscore, your regex should be `/[\W_]/g`.

Answer (score 0):

The `replace` regex is not doing what you think it is doing.  You want to remove all spaces, right?

Change to the following:

```
str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W/g, "").split('');
```

** I edited it to what should remove non-alphanumerics.

Comment: i want to remove all what's not alphanumeric value. so /\W_/ was fine i guess?

Comment: @Gothdo's solution is most correct.  I hadn't tested the underscore, so you did need the underscore within the brackets to match either.  And the '+' I originally had is redundant since you already have the global flag in there.